# Does stress depend on the intrinsic properties of the body?

Tags: pressure, elasticity, stress-strain

I'm trying to understand the difference between stress and pressure.

Assume a body, a box with 4 sides.

We apply pressure to this body, and because the body's right side is 'weak', it deforms.

Does this mean that the stress increases in this example because of the weak side, and therefore, is stress dependent upon the body's intrinsic properties? Had the box been completely rigid, would the stress had been lower?

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you are thinking about the weak point, it wouldn't be the stress that is changing in the material.

The weakness is often a material property where the material has a greater [strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(mechanics)#Strain) for the same amount of stress, so the weak point deforms more when the equal stress is applied throughout the body.

The stress may also depend on the shape of the body.  Weak points can be created through [stress concenrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_concentration).  In this case the object might be weak because it's geometry concentrates the stress at particular locations when the external pressure/load is uniform.

What's important to notice is that stress typically describes the internal forces acting on the object; while pressure describes the force at the surface.  The shape can have a large effect on how the stress develops based on applied pressure; and material properties will affect how the strain compares to applied stress.